# Why chrome browser doesn't launch when running Selenium chrome driver on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting various errors when I'm trying to run a python program using Selenium library and chromedriver. I follow the instructions on Selenium website to install all what I needed and then start programming my two first lines :

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
driver = Chrome()
```

I got this error message :

```
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-dce6fb94cc37> in <module>
      1 from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
      2 
----> 3 driver = Chrome()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py in __init__(self, executable_path, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, chrome_options, keep_alive)
     79                     remote_server_addr=self.service.service_url,
     80                     keep_alive=keep_alive),
---> 81                 desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
     82         except Exception:
     83             self.quit()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in __init__(self, command_executor, desired_capabilities, browser_profile, proxy, keep_alive, file_detector, options)
    155             warnings.warn("Please use FirefoxOptions to set browser profile",
    156                           DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
--> 157         self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
    158         self._switch_to = SwitchTo(self)
    159         self._mobile = Mobile(self)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in start_session(self, capabilities, browser_profile)
    250         parameters = {"capabilities": w3c_caps,
    251                       "desiredCapabilities": capabilities}
--> 252         response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
    253         if 'sessionId' not in response:
    254             response = response['value']

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

so I read many messages and found advice from people who recommend to add options attributes before. So I change my code to this one:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://google.com')
```

But I still don't have any browser windows launch and I can't understand what is happening ... and my log  tells this :

```
/home/lclis/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:8: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
```

I'm looking for any advice or suggestion, I'm a little lost, thank you very much for your help and time to read my post !

PS: I'm on windows10 but using Ubuntu app to code and use Jupyter.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, since you added the `headless option`, the browser won't open any window. Try to remove this line: `chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')`

Comment: Hi thank you for you answer but I still have an error message which is:
`
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

If you have any suggestion ? :)

Comment: I suggest you post a new question with the new problem:)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm posting it right now :)

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, since you added the `headless` option, the browser won't open any window.

Try to remove this line: `chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')`

Answer (score 0):

This first error message...

```
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-dce6fb94cc37> in <module>
      1 from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
      2 
----> 3 driver = Chrome()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py in __init__(self, executable_path, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, chrome_options, keep_alive)
     79                     remote_server_addr=self.service.service_url,
     80                     keep_alive=keep_alive),
---> 81                 desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
     82         except Exception:
     83             self.quit()
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **Browsing Context** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Ideally your code block should have worked out of box, but as you are using `anaconda3` with `ipython` you need to pass the *Key* `executable_path` along with the *Value* set to the *absolute path* of the *ChromeDriver* as follows:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
driver = Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver')
```

---

However, in your second code trial, you were pretty close. This second error message...

```
/home/lclis/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:8: DeprecationWarning: use options instead of chrome_options
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was again unable to initiate/spawn a new **Browsing Context** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Instead of `chrome_options` you should have used `options` as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://google.com')
```