# Can't run Selenium RPA with Python on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: python, selenium, amazon-ec2, rpa

Recently I've developed a RPA using Python and Selenium. Basically my RPA fill some forms to access data from insurance companies and scrape the data filtering the best prices. Running locally everything works perfectly, but then I had to run it on AWS. A lot of errors were thrown and I managed some of them but now I'm struggling with one specific error. That is:

[Error: Chrome is not reachable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnW2n.png)

It's been two days since I'm struggling with it and I think I read most of the topics here at StackOverflow and Github discussions as well. I've added a lot of configurations to my webdriver, checked for installation and all stuff (both chromedriver and google-chrome are in the /usr/bin folder, which is the default location that Selenium will look for). Today I decided to run /usr/bin/google-chrome and received this error:

[Error: Chrome Trap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHDd3.png)

I googled it but found to little information on that. So I decided to ask for help here. Bellow there's a code snippet with all the things I experimented to make this run.

[Code snippet RPA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZy4x.png)

If more information is needed I'll be happy to add it here. Thanks in advance!

**Edit**
The solution proposed in [WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally error using ChromeDriver Chrome and Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59990564/webdriverexception-message-unknown-error-chrome-failed-to-start-exited-abnor) didn't work.